# Taxicab geometry task

Tags: geometry, distance, computational-geometry

So, i've been struggling for some time with this task. It sounds like this: given N points(X,Y) X,Y integers, and M questions of the form P(A, B), find the total distance from point P(A,B) to all the N given points. Distance from A(x1, y1) to B(x2, y2) = max(|x1-x2|, |y1-y2|). Maybe it sounds wierd, i'm not an english speaker, sorry for the mistakes. I'll leave here the IN/OUT

```html
IN.txt (N = 4, M = 3, the first 4 coordinates represent the given points. 
the next 3 coordinates are the points from which i have to compute the total lenght)
4  3
3 5
-3 -2
1 4
-4 -3
2 -4 
1 4
4 2

OUT.txt
28
15
21
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some Python that should do the trick for you. Be sure to pay attention to which directory you're in when you're writing so you don't overwrite things.

I've tested it on the input information you presented in the question, and it works, providing the formatted output file as desired.

```
# Assuming you're in the directory to IN.txt -- otherwise, insert the filepath.
input_file = open("IN.txt", "r")

# Read the input file and split it by new lines
input_lines_raw = input_file.read().split('\n')

input_file.close()


# Split the input lines and eliminate the spaces/create the vector int lists
input_lines_split = []

for element in input_lines_raw:
    input_lines_split.append(element.split(' '))

input_lines = []

for sub in input_lines_split:
    inserter = []
    for elem in sub:
        if (len(elem) > 0):
            inserter.append(elem)
    input_lines.append(inserter)

input_lines = [[int(j) for j in i] for i in input_lines]


# Build the original and final vector arrays
origin_vectors = []
dest_vectors = []

for i in range(1, input_lines[0][0] + 1):
    dest_vectors.append(input_lines[i])

for i in range(input_lines[0][0] + 1, input_lines[0][0] + input_lines[0][1] + 1):
    origin_vectors.append(input_lines[i])

# "Distance" operations on the lists of vectors themselves/generate results array
results_arr = []

for original in origin_vectors:
    counter = 0
    for final in dest_vectors:
        counter = counter + max(abs(original[0] - final[0]), abs(original[1] - final[1]))
    results_arr.append(counter)

print(results_arr)
for element in results_arr:
    print(str(element))

# Open the ouput file and write to it, creating a new one if it doesn't exist.
# NOTE: This will overrwrite any existing "OUT.txt" file in the current directory.
output_file = open("OUT.txt", "w")

for element in results_arr:
    output_file.write(str(element) + '\n')

output_file.close()
```